# Using a var to select a var in Perl

Tags: perl, variables

I thought you used to be able to do this in "strict" mode, but I may be remembering incorrectly. Is is possible for something like this to work...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package SomePackage;

my $TargetPID="demo:5"; #using "our" also works, but not in strict mode
my $VarName="TargetPID";

print ${$VarName}; #works but not in strict or if the var is declared with "my"
exit;
```

The reason I'm interested is that I'm trying to select a variable based on a text flag in a text file and I'd like to read in the content of the text file into a hash, then substitute some identifier along the lines of "#TargetPID#" with the corresponding variable. Being also able to specify both a package and a variable (or constant) would be a nice tbonus.

Comment: You can always create a hash of varnames as keys and substitutions as values

Comment: I may end up having to do that but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a hash?

Comment: If you are willing to use `eval`, use can `eval '$' . $VarName`

Comment: I can live with that, and it works nicely in strict for vars scoped with "my" as well.

I think that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This is a bad data design. Use data structures. That's what they're for.

Comment: @RickSarvas: this is exactly the main case that `use strict 'refs'` is intended to prevent.  If you want to access the data by name, put it in a hash; it isn't "end[ing] up having to do that", it's what you *should* be doing.

Comment: Use a hash.  That's why they're there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of any advantage of doing it the way you are trying to over just using a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package SomePackage;

my %vars = ();
$vars{'TargetPID'}="demo:5";
my $VarName="TargetPID";

print $vars{$VarName};
exit;
```

If you really must use `$TargetPID` as a variable and not a member of a hash, you can use `eval`:

```
my $TargetPID = "demo:5";
my $VarName = '$TargetPID';
print eval $VarName;
```

Or, if for some reason you need the value of `$VarName` to be `'TargetPID'` and not `'$TargetPID'`, you can do `print eval '$' . $VarName`.

Comment: To some extent I'm trying to do that, but I figured there's be a way to that with the existing vars as they are currently defined. Something along the lines of "$SomePackage::{$VarName}" without having to specially define a hash. I suppose I expected that one of the more unusual Perl internal vars would already contain the complete list of vars defined in a similar way that "%ENV" does.

Comment: Ok, I've added an alternative that you might find more palatable.

Comment: @RickSarvas Just curious, which solution did you end up using?

Comment: I started using the eval option and initially it worked great, but when I applied the changes to the SOAP service code I found it doesn't work quite the same (returns nothing). The structure is not quite the same and the code I'm initiating via a SOAP call is in a sub, so it looks like I need to use another approach, like a globally defined hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PadWalker` module for this. From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~robin/PadWalker-1.96/PadWalker.pm):

> PadWalker is a module which allows you to inspect (and even change!)
>   lexical variables in any subroutine which called you. It will only
>   show those variables which are in scope at the point of the call.

In your case, you would need to use `peek_my`, which does what it says: it allows you to peek into variables declared by `my` in a given scope.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

package SomePackage;
use PadWalker qw/peek_my/;

my $TargetPID = "demo:5";
my $VarName = "TargetPID";

print ${peek_my(0)->{'$' . $VarName}}
```

The subroutine `peek_my` takes one argument, a level, which is the number of subroutine calls to go back on the stack. It then returns a hash map of all the lexical `my` variables that were in scope at the time of the given call. In your case, the variable you want is defined in the same scope as where it is needed, so you would pass in `0`, to go back 0 subroutine calls. Then you pull out the data you need like any other hash ref.

Be careful though, from the documentation:

> PadWalker is particularly useful for *debugging* (emphasis mine.) It's even used by
>   Perl's built-in debugger. (It can also be used for evil, of course.)
>
> I wouldn't recommend using PadWalker directly in production code, but
>   it's your call. Some of the modules that use PadWalker internally are
>   certainly safe for and useful in production.